# fragment won't show after hide?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am just learning fragments today. I press a button and it hides a fragment. However if I try to show the fragment nothing happens, why? I was following this tutorial, in the middle I decided to try and make a fragment disappear/appear when I press a button http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Button2 fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button2_fragment,
            container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ButtonFragment fragment = (ButtonFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.ButtonFragment);  
              if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
                 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
                 FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
                 transaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ButtonFragment)); 
                 transaction.commit(); 
              }
              else 
              {
                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
                  FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
                  transaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ButtonFragment)); 
                  transaction.commit(); 
              }       

          }
        });
        return view;
      }
```

I have three fragments like this in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#123456" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ButtonFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.example.myfragment.ButtonFragment" ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/TimeFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.myfragment.TimeFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/Button2Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.myfragment.Button2Fragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code was in my button2 fragment, should I have put something in the main activity?

```
package com.example.myfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ButtonFragment.OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // if the wizard generated an onCreateOptionsMenu you can delete
    // it, not needed for this tutorial

  @Override
  public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
    TimeFragment fragment = (TimeFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.TimeFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
          fragment.setText(link);
        } 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control always seems to be going inside this

`if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout())`

and hence, the fragments are always hidden and never shown, once hidden.

Try to have a toggle, which will keep toggling on every `onClick()` event. That way the control will flow to both the `if` and `else` blocks alternatively, thereby, hiding & displaying the fragments.

Try using `isVisible()` instead of `isInLayout()`

Comment: Thanks, will try that. However I had also tried  if (!fragment.isInLayout()) instead of an else, and that does not work either. Also do you know why if I use remove instead of hide there is a backstack exception?

Comment: thanks changing to isVisible makes things work correctly, apart from .remove, but ill make another thread about that.

Comment: One further question, what did you mean by toggle, I just have an if then an else if.

Comment: by toggle I just meant a `boolean` which will keep changing from **true to false**, and **false to true**, on every `onClick()`